# Syntax confusion in core-site.xml in hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

I followed the solution mentioned in [hadoop core-site.xml syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746277/hadoop-core-site-xml-syntax-error). But it did no good. So writing the post again, error thrown by core-site.xml.

Guest OS:-Ubuntu 20 on Vmware

Host OS: Windows 10

Hadoop 2.9.2
Here is the file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://0.0.0.1:9000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

It is day 5, I am so close to complete map-reduce in hadoop successfully. Please someone help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share/mention the full error log for this ?

Comment: fwiw, you don't need a running Hadoop environment do run Mapreduce code, but `0.0.0.1` is not a valid IP

Comment: Well I was trying to local HDFS  storage place that's why I was using haddop. If you know a quicker way can you please share. Sorry I missed that little devil 1. Thank you so much @OneCricketeer

Comment: Did you know Minio (an S3 equivalent) is faster? https://blog.min.io/hdfsbenchmark/

Comment: never used it, how hard is it to configure?

Comment: refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378568/how-to-find-hadoop-hdfs-directory-on-my-system to locate HDFS directory and make sure you are drill down to directory where hadoop is installed. If "bin/hadoop fs -ls /" shows no o/p means "/" is hdfs directory. use mkdir to create a new dir for map-reduce job [ eg: hdfs fs -mkdir /user/<local_username> ]. After this put or copyfromLocal commands will work. 
I learned this the hardway. I hope someone who is stucked like me finds this helpful

Comment: `minio` is a single binary / command, compared to installing Java+Hadoop, so not hard. Regarding the above comment, `hdfs dfs -ls /` would be the root directory (where there should at least be `/tmp`, by default), and `/user/<name>` would be the default output for `hdfs dfs -ls`